# Read content of a txt file inside a folder which is inside a Zip file

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to read the content of  text files which can or can not be placed inside a folder I am using DotNetZip Library to achieve this

The structure is something like this

Condition 1 :

```
ZipFile/Folder(any name)/List of TXT Files.
```

Condition 2 :

```
ZipFile/List of TXT Files.
```

All the text files have a single row of numerical data which looks something like this .

ABC.txt

```
1000232
1212154
4454457
```

I also need list of these numbers from all the TXT files in a single column of a DataTable

This is what I have tried till now.

```
string pathtoZip = pathtotheZipfile;
        using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(pathtoZip))
        {
            int totalEntries = zip.Entries.Count;

            ZipEntry e  = null; 

            foreach (ZipEntry f in zip.Entries)
            {
                if (f.FileName.Contains("/"))
                {
                    e = f;
                    break;

                }
            }

            if (e.IsDirectory && e != null)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry g in zip.Entries)
                {



                }
            }


        }
```

For converting Text File to A DaTaTable

```
  public DataTable TexttoDataTable(string NewFilePath)

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(NewFilePath);


        dt.Columns.Add();


        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            if (values.Length<=1)
            {
                values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });

            }

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Count(); j++)
                dr[j] = values[j];

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

The Zip can have only one folder but the name of the folder can be different.

Comment: and your question is.... that someone filled in the blanks? or do you have a specific compiler or runtime error to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable("Numbers");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(int), ColumnName = "Num" });
    using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"PATH_TO_ZIP"))
    {
        var entry = zip.GetEntry("PATH_TO_FILE_IN_ZIP");
        {
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = sr.ReadLine();
                        var row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Num"] = line;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```